# Django: the command 'py manage.py runserver' isn't showing any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

the command `py manage.py runserver` isn't showing any output and as far as I could tell isn't opening a server either. I couldn't even get passed the [first tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) in the official django docs.

```
C:\Users\sruls\OneDrive\Desktop\the big fat coding folder\django_playground\django_learn> py manage.py runserver
C:\Users\sruls\OneDrive\Desktop\the big fat coding folder\django_playground\django_learn>
```

none of the code was changed from default and the folder layout is:

```
django_learn/
    manage.py
    django_learn/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
```

I have tried reinstalling Django and it didn't help

Comment: Does running `py` in terminal take you to the interactive terminal?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil yes

Comment: what is the content of manage.py script

Comment: @iklinac the same as how it was by default I didn't change anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of testing it looks like the shebang line wasn't playing well with python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I still don't know why but once I removed it the program ran fine

Answer (score 0):

Try `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: try to create a new project called mysite, and redo everything